How do you rename multiple columns in a table using SQL?
I need to merge some datasets and the tables need to match. The first one I did I used
ALTER TABLE table.name
Rename Column field1 to new_name1,
Rename column field2 to new_name2;
And
ALTER TABLE table.name
Rename Column field1 to new_name1 AND,
field2 to new_name2;
Neither method worked so I had to do each one individually which was a task since I had 12 columns to rename.
Is there another way to rename multiple tables at one time?

You can see the syntax for Sqlite's ALTER TABLE at https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html and see it only allows one column to be renamed at a time.

Maybe the process in section 7 would work for you; make a new table with all the desired column names, copy data over, drop the original table and rename the new one.

Thank you Shawn, I appreciate the feedback.

I think I will just have to rename them one at a time until I figure out how to do it in another language such as R Script. I am still way too new at R Script to do anything except head() and view().
